# Code coverage of a daemon in Windows

Tags: c++, code-coverage, white-box-testing, rational-purify

I need to do code coverage on a daemon. The daemon application is written in c++. We test the daemon features with a client test program that has its own libraries. The libraries communicate with the daemon.

I use IBM Rational PureCoverage usually. But in this situation, when I run the client test program, I can hit only the client libraries and not the daemon libraries.

Is there any other tool that can help with this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

1. Stop The service
2. Use the following command: cove rage /replace=yes /run=no your_service_exe
3. Start the service